# Alfresco folder layout between versions 3, 4, community, and enterprise

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

This is kind of a simple question really.  I am new to alfresco, so when I read articles like [this](http://edlovesjava.blogspot.com/2008/12/extending-share-2-adding-new-content.html) I realize it is old, but it addresses something similar I need to try.  However, I stumble almost right away!  It says:

> In the 'config/alfresco/site-webscripts' source folder in package 'com.orbitz.components.documentlibrary', add ....

How do I map that to Alfresco 4.2?  I have ./tomcat/webapps/share/WEB-INF/classes/site-webscripts, but that is NOT in config/alfresco.  Also, all the directories under there are org/alfresco/something.

Is this something anyone can explain or are such articles simple too out of date to be of use?

Comment: Key line in there is `source folder in package` - you mention that you're working directly on the installed tomcat instance. You either need to mentally map those to the install path, or (better) work on your own source package that you install later

Answer (score 1):

These articles work with projects with ANT tasks.

If you check the addons google code or github and checkout a project, you'll see a similar config folder or resource folder.

If you execute the deploy tasks (with the right settings) it will deploy it to the right Tomcat folders.